# Bootstrap 3 popup transparent and style problem?

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a survey application with datatable, bootstrap, ajax and asp.net mvc. In this poll application I open a popup with bootstrap to add a poll and add and update from here. But I'm having a problem with popup. And I can't find the source of the problem. The popup that pops up does not show the fields in the way I want. For example, the popup's background looks transparent. What may be the problem. I am using Bootstrap 4 javascript and bootstrap 3 css. You will say the versions why if I use bootstrap 4 for css the screen is completely broken. I'm adding the relevant code blocks. I am curious about your comments and evaluations.

Image of created popup [Popup image](https://ibb.co/F30q31r)

[image]

**Popup View**

```
@model MerinosSurvey.Models.Surveys
@{
Layout = null;
}

 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Survey", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return 
 SubmitForm(this)" }))
 {
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SurveyId)
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurveyName, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SurveyName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" 
} })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurveyName)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurveyDescription, new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SurveyDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurveyDescription)
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn" />
</div>


}
```

**Popup Open and Submit**

```
function PopupForm(url) {
        var formDiv = $('<div/>');
        $.get(url)
            .done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);
                Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    title: 'Fill Survey Details',

                    height: 500,
                    width: 700,
                    close: function () {
                        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }

                });
            });
    }


    function SubmitForm(form) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        Popup.dialog('close');
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                        $.notify(data.message,
                            {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success"
                            });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot use bootstrap 4 javascript with bootstrap 3 css...

Comment: @HoomanBahreini thanks dude thank you I changed Bootstrap css and javascript versions to 4 and made changes to layout.cshtml. Problem is solved. This is the source I refer to. https://sensibledev.com/mvc-bootstrap-form-example/    .But I have a small problem. The close button of popup has an icon problem. I'm gonna solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Bootstrap css and javascript versions to 4 and made changes to layout.cshtml. Problem is solved. This is the source I refer to. [reference link](https://sensibledev.com/mvc-bootstrap-form-example/). But I have a small problem. The close button of popup has an icon problem. I'm gonna solve this.